# Round values of a f-curve to be either 0 or 1

Tags: modifiers, fcurves

I would like to transform my baked f-curve in blender. I already scaled it so it's values are between 0 and 1 using the envelope-modifier.
Now i want to transform the f-curve in a way that all values under 0.5 will be set to 0 and all above will be set to 1.0 (so basically rounding the values). Is there a way to achieve this using the f-curve modifiers? I can only think of an difficult solution concluding writing a script.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Add an **Envelope Modifier** with the following settings:

*Reference Value:* `0.5`
*Min:* `-0.5`
*Max:* `0.5`

Add a control point to the Envelope and use *Min* and *Max* bounds of “large” absolute value, but between the allowed range of `-10000` and `10000`, e.g.:

*Frame:* `0`
*Min:* `-9998`
*Max:* `10000`

Finally, add a **Limits Modifier** with *Minimum Y* of `0` and *Maximum Y* of `1`.

[image: modifiers]

The control point's *Min* and *Max* values are important when you care about the rounding of the input value `0.5`.

- With *Min* and *Max* equally distant away from the reference value of `0.5`, the input value of `0.5` will not be modified.
  e.g. *Min* = `-9999`, *Max* = `10000`.
- I used a slightly larger value of `-9998` for *Min* so that the input of `0.5` will be rounded up.
- You can use a slightly smaller value like `-9999` to round the input of `0.5` down.

The size of the bounds will determine how well this method works for values which are close to the reference value. F-Curves with easing near it or keyframes obtained by simulation or experiment might produce numbers which will not be pushed all the way to the intended limits.
For example the image below shows the result of a sinusoidal ease-out over frames `0` to `10` with input values `0.499` to `0.5`. Frame `9` ends up with a value of about `0.75` instead of `0`.

[image: ease problems]

It's not possible to change the control point's bounds beyond `10000`, but if you work with values close to `0.5` you could duplicate the envelope modifier:

[image: ease solution]

Comment: He, thank you for your answer! works great :)I actually tried this before but did not use numbers that were "large" enough. Does the fact that it works with a 1000 mean that the "accuracy" of an f-curve is 0.001? Nevertheless thank you again! :)

Comment: @marvin I edited the answer to try to explain importance of larger numbers and I hope this answers your question. In the original answer I intended to use 1000 instead of a number a few orders of magnitude larger simply to avoid having to count digits. I assumed the maximum values to be the range of Python's float. As it turned out this is not the case. I can't think of any reason not to enter values that don't exhaust the allowed range of 10000.